# Unit Testing RxJava onComplete, onNext and onError

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, kotlin, rx-java

I am unable to find a way to unit test the onComplete, onNext and onError cases for RxJava in android.

TestSubscriber seems to solve the problem, but being new to RXJava, I am still not finding how to do so.

```java
MyApi.method()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(object : Observer<SettleCodeResponse> {
        override fun onCompleted() {
        }

        override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
            view.hideProgress()
            Logger.logError(TAG, e.message)
        }

        override fun onNext(response: SettleCodeResponse) {
            view.hideProgress()
            process(response)
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about Mocking `static` class, but could you try this way.

First you have to mock `MyApi`.

In any class

```
class Foo(private val view: SomeView, private val myApi: MyApi) {
    fun doSomething() {
        myApi.method().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(object : Observer<SettleCodeResponse> {
                override fun onCompleted() {}

                override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                    view.hideProgress()
                    Logger.logError(TAG, e.message)
                }

                override fun onNext(response: SettleCodeResponse) {
                    view.hideProgress()
                    process(response)
                }
            })
    }
}
```

In your test

```
lateinit var myApi: MyApi
lateinit var view: SomeView
lateinit var foo: Foo

@Before
fun setup() {
    RxAndroidPlugins.setInitMainThreadSchedulerHandler({ Schedulers.trampoline() })
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
    myApi = mock(MyApi:class.java)
    view = mock(SomeView::class.java)
    foo = Foo(view, myApi)
}

@Test
fun testOnNext() {
    given(myApi.method()).willReturn(SettleCodeResponse())
    foo.doSomething()
    verify(view).hideProgress()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to mock your `myApi` instance and define the response of `myApi.method()`.

You can use `TestObserver` to assert different scenarios of your Rx chain based on the response.

```
@Test
fun test() {
    //mock the response of the method
    when(myApi.method()).thenReturn(Observable.just(someSettleCodeResponse())

    //create a test observer and subscribe
    val observable: Observable<SettleCodeResponse> = myApi.method()
    val observer: TestObserver<SettleCodeResponse> = TestObserver()
    observable.subscribe(observer)

    //test the observer behaviour
    observer.assertComplete()
            .assertNoErrors()
            .assertValue(someSettleCodeResponse())
}
```

Also you can test the whole flow and see that the `view` methods are called. For this You need to mock your `myApi` as well as `view`. Assuming that code is part of a method in a presenter or view model.

```
@Test
fun anotherTest() {
    //mock the response of the method
    when(myApi.method()).thenReturn(Observable.just(someSettleCodeResponse())

    //call the method you want to test
    presenter.method()

    //test that the view mock methods are called
    verify(view).hideProgress()
}
```